# How to show the intersection points of three functions?

Tags: plotting

How can I show the intersection points of three functions in my `Plot`? I really can't figure it out.

```
LogPlot[{(4.058*10^31)/M, (1.647*10^60)/M^2 , M}, {M, 0, 2*10^20}, 
        PlotRange -> {10^9, 10^21} , Filling -> 3 -> Axis, 
        AxesLabel -> {Subscript[M, U], Subscript["Λ", U]}]
```

Comment: Solve,and then Epilog.Or MeshFunctions

Comment: forgive my ignorance but I dont know why it is not working   Solve[\[CapitalLambda] == (4.058*10^31)/M && \[CapitalLambda] == (
   1.647*10^60)/M^2 && \[CapitalLambda] == M, {\[CapitalLambda], M}]

Comment: Because the three points of intersection are spaced so many orders of magnitude apart, I don't see how a meaningful visualization can be achieved with a single `LogPlot`.

Answer (score 4):

Like said in the comments, use `Solve` and `Epilog`.

```
sel = First[Select[Cases[#1, _Real], #1 > 0 &]] &;
pts = {#, Log@#} & /@ {sel[M /. Solve[(1.647*10^60)/M^2 == M, M]], 
                       sel[M /. Solve[(4.058*10^31)/M == M, M]]};
LogPlot[{(4.058*10^31)/M, (1.647*10^60)/M^2, M}, {M, 0, 2*10^20}, 
  Epilog -> {Red, PointSize@.02, Point@pts}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

```
p1 = {M, Log[(4.058 10^31)/M]} /. 
    Solve[(4.058 10^31)/M == M && M > 0, Reals]
```

> {{6.37024*10^15, 36.3904}}

```
p2 = {M, Log[(1.647 10^60)/M^2]} /. 
  Solve[(1.647 10^60)/M^2 == M && M > 0, Reals]
```

> {{1.18095*10^20, 46.218}}

```
p3 = {M, Log[(1.647 10^60)/M^2]} /. 
  Solve[(1.647 10^60)/M^2 == (4.058 10^31)/M && M > 0, Reals]
```

> {{4.05865*10^28, 6.9076}}

```
plot = LogPlot[
  {(4.058 10^31)/M, (1.647 10^60)/M^2, M}, {M, 0, 2 10^20},
  PlotRange -> {10^9, 10^21},
  Filling -> 3 -> Axis,
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[M, U], Subscript["Λ", U]},
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red,
    Sequence @@ Point /@ p1,
    Sequence @@ Point /@ p2,
    Sequence @@ Point /@ p3}
  ]
```

[image]

Comment: Your epilog can be better written as `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point @@@ {p1, p2, p3}}` or even `Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point @ Join[p1, p2, p3]}`. Also, since `p3` is way off the visible part of the x-axis, you might as well leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see how the three points of intersection can reasonably be displayed on one plot. I would do it with three.

```
{p1, p2, p3} = {{6.37024*10^15, 36.3904}, {1.18095*10^20, 46.218}, {4.05865*10^28, 6.9076}};

plot = LogPlot[{(4.058 10^31)/M, M}, {M, 0, 10 ^16},
  PlotRange -> {10^14, 10^17},
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[M, U], Subscript["Λ", U]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@p1}]
```

[image: plot1]

```
plot = LogPlot[{(1.647 10^60)/M^2, M}, {M, 0, 5 10 ^20},
  PlotRange -> {10^18, 10^21},
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[M, U], Subscript["Λ", U]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@p2}]
```

[image: plot2]

```
plot = LogPlot[{(4.058 10^31)/M, (1.647 10^60)/M^2}, {M, 3 10 ^28, 5 10 ^28},
  PlotRange -> 10^5,
  AxesLabel -> {Subscript[M, U], Subscript["Λ", U]}, 
  Epilog -> {PointSize[Large], Red, Point@p3}]
```

[image: plot3]